# Laravel4 migration column type of Date of Birth

Tags: php, laravel-4, migration

I am very new in laravel.So this is gonna be very basic question.My question is what should be the column type in migration to create **Date of Birth** column.For example,I have created a migration file for Blood Donation,where the columns are something like that,

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('donner_id');
        $table->foreign('donner_id')->references->('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('blood_group');
        $table->string('phone_number')->unique();
        $table->string('location');
        $table-> ------('date_of_birth');
        $table->timestamps();
```

you can see that laravel4 migration uses 'string'  type instead of 'varchar'.so what should be the type of Date of birth column in **laravel 4** ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Date would be the most suitable](http://laravel.com/docs/schema#adding-columns)

```
$table->date('date_of_birth');
```

Comment: is it as simple as that?